# In Perl, how can I parse a string that might contain many email addresses to get a list of addresses?

Tags: perl, parsing, email-address

I want to split the a string if it contains `;` or `,`.

For example:

```
$str = "a@a.com;b@b.com,c@c.com;d@d.com;";
```

The expected result is:

```
result[0]="a@a.com";
result[1]="b@b.com";
result[2]="c@c.com";
result[3]="d@d.com";
```

Comment: You must always enable warnings: `perl -we '$x = "a@acom"`: *Possible unintended interpolation of @acom in string at -e line 1.*

Answer (score 11):

Sure, you can use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) as shown by others. However, if `$str` contains full blown email addresses, you will be in a world of hurt.

Instead, use [Email::Address](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email%3a%3aAddress):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Email::Address;
use YAML;

print Dump [ map [$_->name, $_->address ],
    Email::Address->parse(
        q{a@a.com;"Tester, Test" <test@example.com>,c@c.com;d@d.com}
    )
];
```

Output:

```
---
-
  - a
  - a@a.com
-
  - 'Tester, Test'
  - test@example.com
-
  - c
  - c@c.com
-
  - d
  - d@d.com
```

Comment: Good point, +1.  Works even better if your example includes something like `"Tester, Test" <test@example.com>` (which many mailers produce).

Answer (score 6):

```
my $str = 'a@a.com;b@b.com,c@c.com;d@d.com;';
my @result = split /[,;]/, $str;
```

Note that you can't use double-quotes to assign `$str` because `@` is special. That's why I replaced the string delimiters with a single-quote. You could also escape them like so:

```
my $str = "a\@a.com;b\@b.com,c\@c.com;d\@d.com;";
```

Comment: Probably should do something like `grep { $_ } split(/[,;]/, $str)` to prevent a blank entry at the end of the list.

Comment: @mscha: There's no need. By default, the `split` function deletes empty trailing fields.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `@` interpolates in a double-quoted string. The OP must not have enabled warnings.

Answer (score 1):

split(/[.;]/, $str)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Text::Csv and use either ";" or "," for splitting. It helps to look at other things like printable characters etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

To [split](http://p3rl.org/split) by ";" or ","

```
$test = "abc;def,hij";
@result = split(/[;,]/, $test);
```

Where the regex means to match on an escaped ; or , character.
The end result will be that @result = ['abc','def','hij']

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title of the mail (a little different from its text):

```
my $str = 'abc@xyz;qwe@rty;';

my @addrs = ($str =~ m/(\w+\@[\w\.]+)/g);

print join("<->", @addrs);
```